# SSH Brute Force Dictionaries

Tags: network, ssh, brute-force, logging, research

**Request for logs please.**

So, I had an interesting question posed to me around geographical trends in SSH brute force attempts. The question being "has anybody ever looked into the prevalent SSH username lists by country?"

I happen to think that this would be an interesting little project and would like to do some research but to make this a statistically useful exercise will require access to more logs than I have.

So, would any of you be willing to share SSH logs for failed passwords /invalid users?

The logs would need to contain the source IP and enough verbose detail for me to see either a failed password attempt or an invalid user name used.

Comment: Good luck with getting people to hand over these logs... ;)

Comment: Given enough time to sanitize them, maybe. There are existing lists like this out there in various forms of public accessibility.

Comment: Not asking for anything sensitive - as an example this is one of the logs being sent to me for this project:

Dec 17 12:56:11 cronos sshd[25122]: Failed password for root from 66.11.xxx.xxx port 46635 ssh2

Answer (score 3):

Like [Project Honeypot](http://projecthoneypot.org/dictionary_attacker_usernames.php)?

These are spam harvesters, but the idea is the same.  [By country](http://projecthoneypot.org/harvester_top_countries.php)

Comment: useful links - cheers.